# Dynamic Theming On lutter

Tags: flutter, dart, themes

i want to dynamically change the theme color of my app based on my phone system. Like if i set my phone to dark mode, my app turns dark and if i set it to light mode, it gets bright. I have been all around the internet but all i am seeing are people doing it using a button. If there is a way, perhaps through a dependency, i would love to know. I also want to see if i can somehow change the color of my scaffold dynamically too. my code

```
main.dart
import 'package:figma_test/home/home.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
          statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
          statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark
      ));
  runApp(
      const MyApp()
  );

}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final lightTheme = ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.light,
  primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
);

final darkTheme = ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.dark,
  primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey,
  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
);
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,

      ),
      home:  Home(),
    );
  }
}




home.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
   Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final List<String> _images = [

    'img1.jpeg',
    'img2.jpeg',
    'img3.jpeg',
    'img4.jpeg',
    'img5.jpeg'
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xfffafafa),
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(30),
        child: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 15),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                   const Icon(Icons.close),

                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 13,
                  ),
                  Text('Product Name',
                    style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      fontSize: 22
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 400,
             child: ListView.builder(
               scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,

               itemCount: _images.length,
                 itemBuilder: (context, index){
                 return  Padding(
                   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                   child: Container(
                     height: 400,
                     width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.9,
                     decoration: BoxDecoration(
                       image: DecorationImage(
                           image: AssetImage('asset/images/${_images[index]}',),
                               fit: BoxFit.fill
                       ),
                         boxShadow: [
                           BoxShadow(
                               color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                               blurRadius: 2,
                               spreadRadius: 2,
                               offset: const Offset(
                                   1.0,
                                   2.0
                               )
                           )
                         ],
                         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                         color: Color(0xffe7edf9)
                     ),
                   ),
                 );
                 }
             ),
           )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but you can  easily change the theme based on the user's system theme.

In `MaterialApp()` you can set the `themeMode` property to either:

- `ThemeMode.dark`
- `ThemeMode.light`
- **`ThemeMode.system`**

---

Here's how I use it in my code:

```
return MaterialApp( 
    darkTheme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark), 
    theme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.light), 
    themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
```

- If the user's system theme is dark, the app will use the `darkTheme:`
  theme.
- If the user's system theme is light, the app will use the
  `theme:` theme.